# How to convert $12x =3 \pmod {93}$ to a form that can be used with the Euclidean algorithm?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know that if I have to solve, for example, ${17x}\pmod {83} = 1$, I can convert that equation to $17x + 83y = 1$, and this latter equation can be used with the Euclidean algorithm.

How should I convert $12x = 3 \pmod {93}$ to a form that can be used with the Euclidean algorithm as well?

Comment: $12x\equiv 3\pmod{93}\iff 4x\equiv 1\pmod{31}$.

Comment: @AlexM. note that user236182 canceled the modulus also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just go $12x+93y=3$, then you can divide by $3$ to obtain $4x+31y=1$

Answer (score 0):

$12x\equiv3 \ (\mbox{mod} \ 93)\Leftrightarrow 4x\equiv1 \ (\mbox{mod} \ 31)\Leftrightarrow 4x+31y=1$